# Get the COUNT(*) in the case with 'JOIN and WHERE'

Tags: mysql

There are three tables, relationship between them :

> 'Task' is created by 'employer(uid)'
>
> 'Execution' is complete by 'employee(uid)' and match to 'task(tid)'

### Table 1 - task

```
tid | name        | employer
==========================
  1 | Hello world | 1
  2 | Eat food    | 1
  3 | Swimming    | 2
```

### Table 2 - user

```
uid | name
=============
  1 | Salmon
  2 | Bird
  3 | Pig
```

### Table 3 - execution

```
eid | task | employee
======================
  1 |    1 |        2
  2 |    1 |        2
  3 |    2 |        3
  4 |    1 |        3
  5 |    2 |        2
```

---

Then I do some queries.

```
SELECT T1.tid,
    T1.name AS taskName,
    T1.employer AS employerUid,
    T2.name AS employerName,
    COUNT(T3.*)
FROM task T1, user T2, execution T3
WHERE T1.employer = T2.uid
    AND T1.tid = T3.task
    AND T1.tid = ( Here can input the task id )
```

My question :

I input the `'T1.tid = 1'` to query, I want to get the `COUNT()` result that is `'3'`.

```
eid | task | employee
======================
  1 |    1 |        2  ---- I want
  2 |    1 |        2  ---- I want
  3 |    2 |        3
  4 |    1 |        3  ---- I want
  5 |    2 |        2
```

But SQL always return `'5'`, I guess the `'5'` means Table-execution total rows.

How can I get the `COUNT` in above case?

---

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a JOIN rather than trying to jam everything into the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT T1.tid,
    T1.name AS taskName,
    T1.employer AS employerUid,
    COUNT(*)
FROM task T1
JOIN execution T3 ON T3.task = T1.tid
JOIN user T2 ON T3.eid = T2.uid
WHERE T1.tid = ( Here can input the task id )
```

Note that you can leave off the line with JOIN user T2 entirely, since it's not relevant when you are counting. Also I omitted displaying the employee number when counting, since there will be many such employees. You could also change the WHERE to a GROUP BY and show the counts for all tid's in a single query, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select T1.tid as task, count(T2.id) as employee 
from task T1
    inner join execution T3 on T3.task = T1.tid
    inner join employee T2 on T3.employee = T2.eid
group by T1.id
order by T1.id;
```

I am assuming you want to count the employee T2 and not the execution T3?

Sorry if there's typo I don't have access to MySQL at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have an aggregate function in the select (like COUNT) you have to include how you want to group records to be aggregated.  Normally the fact that your query doesn't have a GROUP BY clause would give an error, rather than weird results.  Maybe MySQL is more permissive in that regard.

GROUP BY T3.task